# Storing files in vb .net then distribut it on execution

Tags: vb.net

Is possible to store files inside a vb program then place them in the folder that the vb program is located in on execution.

To clarify what im saying  Ill go through exactly what I'm trying to do.

Files (text documents) are stored into myprogram.exe; somehow client places my program in his documents folder and runs myprogram.exe. Files that were stored inside are placed in documents folder.

I'm trying to make an auto addon installer.

Answer (score 1):

No need to write an application for this purpose.

Use a utility like IZArc - http://www.izarc.org/

Zip the files and convert that zip into a self-extracting executable. You can specify default extract folder and other settings.

Comment: Probably the best solution

Answer (score 0):

My installer written with WiX routinely does that.
Alternatively, you can use the ClickOnce installer, add all relevant files to your project and set all files to "copy". Then when you install your program, it will extract the files too.

Comment: Thanks much ill look into ClickOnce Installer. Is your installer on any sort of website so i might be able to use that instead ?

Comment: Nope, but you can deploy it via web.